# Bash Script to Check That Files Are Being Created

Tags: bash, ubuntu

We have an Amazon EC2 instance where we upload output from our security cameras. Every now and then, the cameras have an issue, stop uploaded, and need to be rebooted. The easy way for us to determine this is by seeing if the files are not being created. The problem is it creates lots and lots of files. If I use find with -ctime, it takes a very long time for this script to run. Is there a faster way to check to see if files have been created since yesterday? I just need to capture the result, (yes there are some files, or not there are not,) and email a message, but it would be nice to have something that didn't take half an hour to run.

```
 #!/bin/bash

 find /vol/security_ftp/West -ctime -1
 find /vol/security_ftp/BackEntrance -ctime -1
 find /vol/security_ftp/BoardroomDoor -ctime -1
 find /vol/security_ftp/MainEntrance -ctime -1
 find /vol/security_ftp/North -ctime -1
 find /vol/security_ftp/South -ctime -1
```

Comment: can your change things so that each day's files are written to a separate dir, ie. `/vol/2014/11/11/security_ftp/West` ... ? or `/vol/security_ftp/2014/11/11/West` ... ? Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `find` is a natural solution, but if you really must avoid it, you can see the newest file in a directory using `ls` and sorting the output according to ctime, eg.

```
ls /vol/security_ftp/West -clt | head --lines=1
```

This would be enough if you want to see the date.
If you need better formatted output (or only ctime to process it further) you can feed the filename to `stat`:

```
stat --format="%z" $( ls /vol/security_ftp/West -ct | head --lines=1 )
```

This does not answer automatically if any file was created recently, though.

Comment: I like this last one. It's very fast. Thanks. Sorry for the slow response, guys, I was away at the Amazon Reinvent conference.

Answer (score 1):

The simple (and recommended `man find`) solution is:

```
find /vol/security_ftp/ -mtime 0
```

To find files in `/vol/security_ftp` modified within the last 24 hours. Give it a try and see if it will meet your time requirements. We can look for another solution if the default can't do it quick enough. If the delay is due to numerous subdirectories under `/vol/security_ftp`, then limit the depth and type with:

```
find /vol/security_ftp/ -maxdepth 1 -type f -mtime 0
```